# Anaconda + GCC in a gitlab-ci job

Tags: python, gcc, theano, gitlab-ci

I am working with the Theano python library, that needs a C++ compiler to accelerate computations. I would like to accelerate my test suite in gitlab-ci.

Therefore, I need to configure a gitlab-ci job to have both Python and GCC

I tried the following :

- add the [GCC docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/gcc/) as a service in gitlab-ci.yml, but it did not work because GCC is a classic command and could not boot as a service
- Add the [libgcc](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/libgcc) conda package. Did not work, g++ could not be found either
- I need GCC along with Python during runtime, because Theano performs compilation during program execution, so there is no way split the job in two with one using GCC image for build and a second one with Python
- Ideally I'd like to avoid creating my own docker image

Any ideas on how to solve this ?